# Swift ui create buttons in xcode style

Tags: swift, xcode, user-interface, button, swiftui

[image]

How do I make a button like the blue one shown in the image?

```swift
Button("Done") {
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a default style button and is managed by keyboard shortcut, like

```
var body: some View {
    HStack {
        Button("Done") {}
        Button("Clone") {}
            .keyboardShortcut(.defaultAction) // << here !!
    }
}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thx, if you have time I can ask you if you can take a look here, I would like to know your opinion. ;)